# How to add mouseover event for an option element inside a select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, web

How to add mouseover event for an option element inside a select tag?

It is working for select with mutiple option selection but not supported for select with single option selection.
Is there a reason for this behavior?

Below is the sample to reproduce:
[sample to see in action](https://jsbin.com/mumizujatu)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

<select id="pet-select" multiple>
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option onmouseover="console.log('hello1')" value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option onmouseover="console.log('hello1')" value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
  </div>
    <div style="margin-top:30px">
  <select id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option onmouseover="console.log('hello2')" value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option onmouseover="console.log('hello2')" value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting question. I think it could be to do with the fact that the 'popup' nature of the select dropdown being rendered differently by browsers. Have you tried building your own frontend to a select field like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp. By using pseudo elements as the dropdown you may be able to grab a hover state from it?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for that I do not know the reason for it, but I could help you find a solution for it.

I have added `css` to the `id` of `pet-select > option` then added a style to `onhover` event :

So the code will come as:

```css
#pet-select[multiple='multiple']>option:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      #pet-select[multiple='multiple']>option:hover {
        background-color: blue !important;
        color: white !important;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div><select id="pet-select" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      </select></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;"><select id="pet-select">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      </select></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems you misunderstood my question. I'm actually looking for addition of mouseover event(JS way) but not css related state which cannot be helpful for business logic(like javascript).